# regex for comma separated string (2 strings separated by comma)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not good at regex, and i'm looking for a regex solution for the below comma separated string in javascript

I have a string in this format:

```
"string1,string2"
```

> **condition:**
>
> 1 - Both string1 and string2 can contain only alphabets.
>   2 - Both string1 and string2 length shall not be more than 20
>   3 - string1 and string2 can not be empty
>   4 - only 2 string can be present (string1,string2,string shall be invalid)

Example ::

```
Edward,john = valid
Edward,  john = Invalid
12*&,john = Invalid      (shall not accept either special character or numbers)
Edward,12# = Invaid 
,          = Invalid
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee,jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj = Invalid length (more than 20)
```

Comment: Can you give examples of strings you want to match and not to match?

Comment: @vivek, there are plenty of regex generators out there, and all you need is some basic googling skills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Both string1 and string2 can contain only alphabets.

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

The `-` is used to represent a range in character classes. Here we say that, it can be any alphabet between `a` and `z` or `A` and `Z`.

> 2. Both string1 and string2 length shall not be more than 20
> 3. string1 and string2 can not be empty

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,20}
```

It means that, match minimum 1 and maximum 20 alphabets.

> 4. only 2 string can be present (string1,string2,string shall be invalid)

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1,20},[a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/
```

`^` represents the beginning of string and `$` represents the end of the string.

---

You can check that the RegEx works fine for all your inputs mentioned in the question, like this

```
var invalid_cases = ['Edward,  john', '12*&,john', 'Edward,12#', ',         ',
        'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee,jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj'],
    valid_cases = ['Edward,john'],
    regEx = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,20},[a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/;

valid_cases.forEach(function(currentString) {
    console.assert(regEx.exec(currentString)[0] === currentString);
});

invalid_cases.forEach(function(currentString) {
    console.assert(regEx.exec(currentString) === null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , u save my day . gonna accept this as answer.